# Split one column into two, retain original value if there aren't two values

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr, stringr

I have a column with specific gene locations in my data frame. It either has the single location (in case of a SNP) or it has a range for the locations (in case of Deletion, Duplication).

I want to split the Gene_Locations column into two columns: Start_Position, Stop Position. Where it has a range, this is easy enough to do. But where there is only one value, I want it to retain the original value in the Gene_Location column, in both the Start_position and Stop_position columns. The second bit has not been easy to do as it it keeps coming up with NA, or a blank whitespace. I'd be grateful for help with this.

This is my expected column:

| GeneLocation | Start_Position | Stop_Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123456 | 123456 |
| 123456 - 123457 | 123456 | 123457 |
| 122345 - 122346 | 122345 | 122346 |
| 134567 | 134567 | 134567 |
| 123456 | 123456 | 123456 |

This is my actual column:

| GeneLocation | Start_Position | Stop_Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123456 | NA |
| 123456 - 123457 | 123456 | 123457 |
| 122345 - 122346 | 122345 | 122346 |
| 134567 | 134567 | NA |
| 123456 | 123456 | NA |

```
dat2 <- data %>% separate(GeneLocation, c('Start_Position', 'Stop_Position'))
```

Comment: One way would be to add `df$Stop_Position = dplyr::coalesce(df$Stop_Position, df$Start_Position)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it has worked like a charm and saved me a lot of time googling!

Comment: ...or as part of your chain, add `%>% mutate(Stop_Position = coalesce(Stop_Position, Start_Position))`

Comment: @Jon Spring. Please provide this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for `dplyr::coalesce`, which (akin to the SQL function it's named for) returns the first non-NA element from a set of vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  separate(GeneLocation, c('Start_Position', 'Stop_Position')) %>%
  mutate(Stop_Position = coalesce(Stop_Position, Start_Position))
```

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce` is perfect for this use case!
Here is  solution with an `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(GeneLocation, into = c("Start_Position", "Stop_Position"), sep = " - ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Stop_Position = ifelse(is.na(Stop_Position), Start_Position, Stop_Position))
```

```
     GeneLocation Start_Position Stop_Position
1          123456         123456        123456
2 123456 - 123457         123456        123457
3 122345 - 122346         122345        122346
4          134567         134567        134567
5          123456         123456        123456
```